# embedding flash using swfobject in drupal 6.x dimensions issue

Tags: flash, drupal, embed, swfobject

I embedded flash to my site using this:

```
print swf('myflash.swf');
```

into my page.tpl file however it is not recognizing the orig dimensions when using this:

```
print swf('myflash.swf',array('height'=>400,'width'=>700));
```

But the flash is showing up, only the dimensions had the problems. I have been searching and searching around in Google and drupal forums to no avail for a few days now..

If anyone out there had the same issue please help I am so stuck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The swf function from the SWF Tools module is expecting something more like this:

```
print swf ('myflash.swf', array('params'=>array('height'=>400,'width'=>700)));
```

If params doesn't work, here are the other keyed values it is looking for:

```
  // Initialise any $options array elements that weren't passed by the caller
  $options += array(
    'params' => array(),
    'flashvars' => array(),
    'othervars' => array(),
    'methods' => array(),
  );
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it simply worked! One more question though... my flash movie includes the menu for the site however, the pages they are linked to no longer works. Also, If I do this -> print swf('myflash.swf?button=2') it goes back to my original message....

Comment: scratch the flashvars issue, i fixed it. The only thing now is the menus in the flash file is still not working.. any ideas?

Comment: What are you expecting with the menu and what is happening?  How does your flash file get the information to generate the menu? For example, do you need to pass in a flashvar of an xml file that has the menu titles and links or is the info hardcoded in the flash file?

Comment: the flash file has hard coded the menu so it's fixed in the flash file. The flash vars i was passing was just to identify the default menu button so it will highlight when someone clicks. And on the flash file, the menu will just use getURL('/general-info') to change the page in drupal. It was working before using the direct embedding but when using the print swf() method the menu stopped getting to the pages. Nothing happens when clicking on it...

Comment: I would start by viewing the source of the rendered HTML page when you use the SWF function, and compare the flash code to what you use directly. See if there are any obvious differences.  I feel it necessary to mention that the best practice would be not to use flash at all for the menu. If anyone wants to change a title, link, etc they would need you to re-compile the flash. Consider using Drupal's nice_menu module which is easily styled, or superfish, or any of the many other menu plugins. Good luck!